# Pause on failure, retry input from CSV

Tags: powershell, powercli

I have 2 sections of PowerShell code that exit the script on failure.  After thinking about it I realized it would make more sense to pause on a failure and allow the admin time to remediate... then when the any key is paused, retry the same line in the CSV.  Here's how it looks now:

```
#check tools status first
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Checking VMware Tools Status before proceeding." -foreground green
Write-Host ""
foreach ($item in $vmlist) {
    $vmname = $item.vmname
    $ToolsStatus = (Get-VM $vmname).extensiondata.Guest.ToolsStatus -eq "toolsNotRunning"
    if ($ToolsStatus -eq $true) {
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "Tools is not installed or running on $vmname. Remediate on guest and restart the script" -foreground Yellow
        Write-Host "Script will continue to exit until tools is running on $vmname" -foreground yellow
        Write-Host ""
        exit
    } else {
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "Tools running on all VMs, script will continue" -foreground green
        Write-Host ""
    }
}
```

I know how to put the pause in `$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown')`, but I have no idea to do the loop so it retries.

I'm using similar code elsewhere to validate that VMs are powered up so this will work in both sections.

EDIT:  Here's the re-worked script. Would this work?

```
foreach ($item in $vmlist) {
    $vmname = $item.vmname
    do {
        $ToolsStatus = (Get-VM $vmname).extensiondata.Guest.ToolsStatus -eq "toolsNotRunning"
        if ($ToolsStatus) {
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "Tools is not installed or running on $vmname." -Foreground yellow
            Write-Host "Remediate VMware tools on $vmname and"
            Write-host "Press any key to retry..."
            $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown')
        }
    } until ($ToolsStatus -eq "PoweredOn")
    Write-Host "Tools running on $vmname, script will continue" -Foreground green
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a nested `do..while` loop like this:

```
foreach ($item in $vmlist) {
    $vmname = $item.vmname
    do {
        $ToolsMissing = (Get-VM $vmname).extensiondata.Guest.ToolsStatus -eq "toolsNotRunning"
        if ($ToolsMissing) {
            Write-Host "Tools is not installed or ..." -Foreground yellow
            $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown')
        }
    } while ($ToolsMissing)
}

Write-Host "Tools running on all VMs, script will continue" -Foreground green
```

Comment: Will that retry the same line (e.g. $vmname)  from the csv?

Comment: Also, could I do it as a do-until with the pause?

Comment: Basically do-until ($ToolsStatus -eq 'PoweredOn')?

Comment: Sure. Add a `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200` to the loop, though, so it doesn't consume all CPU resources.

Comment: And yes, the loop will repeat for the same `$item` until it stops returning "toolsNotRunning".

Comment: Where would I add the Start-sleep?  To the until?

Comment: I added the updated section to the question, does that work?

Comment: No, that won't work. The `Get-VM` line produces a boolean value, so comparing `$ToolsStatus -eq "PoweredOn"` won't do what you seem to expect. Either remove the comparison from the `Get-VM` line and compare `$ToolStatus` in the `if` and `until` conditions, or keep the comparison in the `Get-VM` line and just use the boolean value in the `if` and `until` conditions. And you don't need a sleep if you have a `ReadKey()` in the loop.

Comment: So it should be -ne "toolsNotRunning" or change it at the top to -ne "PoweredOn" and later -ne "PoweredOn"